# Proving $\bar{A} = \text{int}(A) \cup \partial A$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

This might seem like a duplicate, but I couldn't find anyone proving it like this. I feel like my proof is wrong because I couldn't find anyone doing it this way. It would be helpful if anyone can verify it for me.

Let's lay down some definitions. Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$.

> By $\bar{A}$, I mean the closure of $A$. By $\text{int}(A)$, I mean the interior of $A$.

And here's probably the most important definition in this question.

> By $\partial A$, I mean the boundary of $A$ and I choose the definition that $\partial A = \bar{A} \backslash \text{int}(A)$.

Using this definition, I found that it was *rather easy* to prove the following claim.

> Claim: Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$. Then $\bar{A} = \text{int}(A) \cup \partial A$

**Proof.** By definition of the boundary, we have that
\begin{equation}
\text{int}(A) \cup \partial A = \text{int}(A) \cup (\bar{A} \backslash \text{int}(A))
\end{equation}
Observe that $\bar{A} \backslash \text{int}(A) = \bar{A} \cap (X \backslash \text{int}(A))$. Moreover, it is true for any sets $S, T, U$ that $S \cup (T \cap U) = (S \cup T) \cap (S \cup U)$. Thus,

\begin{equation}
\text{int}(A) \cup (\bar{A} \backslash \text{int}(A)) = \text{int}(A) \cup \{ \bar{A} \cap (X \backslash \text{int}(A))\} = \{ \text{int}(A) \cup \bar{A} \} \cap \{ \text{int}(A) \cup (X \backslash \text{int}(A))\}
\end{equation}
Now, $\text{int}(A) \cup (X \backslash \text{int}(A)) = X$. Also, we have that $\text{int}(A) \subset A \subset \bar{A}$. Thus, we have that 
\begin{equation}
\text{int}(A) \cup (\bar{A} \backslash \text{int}(A)) = \text{int}(A) \cup \bar{A} = \bar{A}
\end{equation}
But the LHS is just $\text{int}(A) \cup \partial A$, so we have really proven
\begin{equation}
\bar{A} = \text{int}(A) \cup \partial A
\end{equation}
as required.

Comment: You're correct that if you take this as the definition of $\partial A$, then this is trivial. In a first year analysis course however, often $\partial A$ is defined as $\bar{A}\cap \bar{A^C}$. Then this is no longer so trivial

Comment: "I feel like my proof is wrong because I couldn't find anyone doing it this way." I think your proof is correct. I want to verify though, you do know that there is a much easier proof?

Comment: @SmileyCraft Thanks for verifying. Sorry, I don't really know. Is it the same as posted in the current answer below by DiegoG7?

Comment: @AdamMartens Ahh I see. Thanks!

Comment: @devianceee Yes, that is also what I had in mind.

Comment: I see, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of closure and interior,
$$
A\subset  \bar{A},\quad \text{int}(A)\subset A
$$
then $\text{int}(A)\subset \bar{A} $.

Now $\partial A = \bar{A} \backslash \text{int}(A)$ implies $\bar{A} = \text{int}(A)\cup \partial A $ simply by an identity on set operations:

$X=Y\setminus Z\quad \textrm{and} \quad Z\subset Y \Rightarrow Y=X\cup Z$

Comment: This is brilliant! I'm quite embarrassed now that I did not see this earlier.